# Pure CSS range slider whose background color changes based on progress/value

Tags: html, css, browser

I've been looking to build a range slider which changes the background color of the filled portion based on the current progress value. For example, be greener if closer to 0, yellow in the middle and gets more red towards the maximum value.

This is the current CSS for my slider:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  input[type='range'] {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px #e1e4e8 solid;
    outline-width: 0;
  }

  input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: red;
    margin-top: -1px;
  }

  input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width: 4px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 10px;
    background: #24292e;
    box-shadow: -80px 0 0 80px red;
  }
}

/* FF */
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: red;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {  
  background-color: white;
}

/* IE */
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: red;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {  
  background-color: white;
}
```

I'm not sure if this can be done with just CSS, but I'd prefer to not use JS at all. I believe that with some browser-specific elements it may be possible?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to involve some JS

Comment: @Stuart my current slider is pure CSS, as shown in the code. I'm looking to how it's possible to alter the background color without resorting to JS

Comment: ...for example: https://codepen.io/Manitoba/pen/ZWRjye

Comment: @Stuart Not possible without JS.